# L_infinity norm of signed sums of Fourier characters and discrepancy of Fourier matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, discrepancy-theory

Consider signed sums $\displaystyle A_f(x) =\sum_{\chi} (-1)^{f(\chi)} \chi(x)$ for some set $S$ of characters of an abelian group $G$, and signing $f$ of the characters. For a fixed set $S$ what is the signed sum with minimum $\ell_{\infty}$ norm? That is what is the discrepancy

$$ \min_{f} \max_{x \in G} \displaystyle |\sum_{\chi \in S} (-1)^{f(\chi)} \chi(x)|$$

in terms of the size of $S$? For instance, if $S$ is all non-zero elements in $G = \mathbb Z/p$, then the signing given by Legendre symbol $\left( \frac{x}{p}\right)$ gives a bound of $O(\sqrt {|S|}) = O(\sqrt p)$, and you cannot do better.

We can think of the quantity we want as the discrepancy of a submatrix of the Fourier matrix restricted to some columns. So the question is how the discrepancy varies with $S$. Does the discrepancy of a random set of characters $S$ look like $\sqrt{|S| \log |G|/|S| }$ (guaranteed by Spencer's theorem) or is it much smaller?

Related question: [Growth rate of the infinity norm of Discrete Fourier Transform of +1,-1 vectors](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103364/growth-rate-of-the-infinity-norm-of-discrete-fourier-transform-of-1-1-vectors)
They discuss the case of the full Fourier matrix, what do we know about the submatrices of Fourier matrix?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.